# Как создать символьную ссылку на сетевой диск в Windows XP?

Tags: windows, ссылки

Есть веб сервак хампп (Ос Win Xp). Установлен по пути "С:\webservak"

Вопрос: как читать файлики которые находятся в сетевом диске, который подключен к компу как устройство Z. В сетевухе есть папка "video" , а там видеофайлики. Мне нужно с помощью флеша воспроизвести эти видеофайлики. А апач не хочет читать с сетевого диска.

Comment: А вот такой [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431658/apache-network-drive-alias) Stackoverflow пробовали?

Answer (score 1):

Что то действительно не понял. Но попытаюсь помочь так, как я понял. Вам нужен ярлык на который бы вы кликнули и попали на сетевой диск ?! То просто кликните правой кнопкой мыши на рабочем столе и создайте просто ярлык, который в свою очередь запросит путь до определенной программы либо сетевого пути. Думаю я правильно вас понял.

Comment: Да,все верно. Но простые ссылки не подходять,так как у них есть расширение. Мне нужно как папка и в то же время ссылался к сетевухе. Чтоб просто апачу указать как локальный путь "/video/"

Answer (score 1):

Дабы не удалять гланды, через задний проход, с помощью автогена, индейца надо поставить в родной для него среде, где нет понятий сетевой диск или диск X

Comment: нашел солюшн.всем спасибо!